# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Vietnamese font render on Discord

Tags: 20.04, system-installation

I'm using LTS 20.04 Ubuntu with default font settings. But somehow, system rendered my vietnamese font with some problem. Some characters look diffrent with other when using unicode. Is there anyway to fix it?

[image: Error render with Vietnamese Unicode screenshot]